# ctrl+s not being sent in autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

i.e. hitting ctrl+s should activate ctrl+s...the below does not work. Neither does the simpler
SendInput, ^s. Goal is to have ctrl+s save current doc and then load another via more code, the saving part never works tho. The bad code, depending on where i put sleep or no sleep, either returns s or shift s (in 1 code editor anyways) or nothing. I basically want a hotkey that mimics itself.

```
F4::ExitApp  
<^s::  
send, {lctrl down}  
SLEEP 300  
SEND s  
SLEEP 300  
SEND {lctrl up}  
return
```

Comment: Maybe try a combined character approach. Sending sequentially as you're doing probably won't cut it. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/83864-send-c-vs-send-ctrl-downcctrl-up/

Comment: you'll have to be more specific, ive tried all those things and read that post earlier.

Comment: Ok. Then probably not useful. Apologies I was only looking at your above script which looked like a sequence of keys rather than a simultaneous press.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that the issue your program is running into is that having the ^s send another ^s inside of itself is creating an infinite recursive loop in which nothing is ever able to run past the place you invoke ^s. To prevent this, we can use the `$` modifier as so:

```
$<^s::  
SendInput ^s
return
```

From the relevant section of [the Modifier section of the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm):

> **This is usually only necessary if the script uses the Send command to
> send the keys that comprise the hotkey itself, which might otherwise
> cause it to trigger itself**. The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to
> be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the
> Send command from triggering it. The $ prefix is equivalent to having
> specified #UseHook somewhere above the definition of this hotkey.

---

Edit: it seems to work fine for me even if I remove the `$` modifier. Testing the following code shows me there appears to be no problems regarding code execution before, after, or during the `SendInput` statement.

```
<^s::  
MsgBox no
SendInput, ^s
MsgBox yes
return
```

Maybe check your version or installation of AHK?

Comment: the hook fixed it. im one patch behind. 1.1.32 instead of 33. the old code is working properly now as well. i dont kno why. only change was i woke the pc from sleep....so the hook fixed something or something wasnt loaded properly last boot and sleep+wake fixed something. this pc sometimes fails to load things...like the mouse drivers among others.

Comment: nvm, it stopped working without the use of the keyhook. keyhook is the fix